# Why it leads to runtimeException when creating a new project?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I try to create an empty project(generated by idea/android studio). It leads to "Exception in plugin Android support" and the procedure of creating a new project failed.

I try to solve it by changing SDK version(from API24 to API21), disabling Android support, disabling Kotlin Sopport and etc. None of them works.
Do I need to reinstall idea?

Comment: Please share the exception and specify your IDE version.

Comment: Did you remember to restart after you disabled the plugins. And upgrade to latest IDEA is probably a good idea.

Comment: I did but nothing works. After that I install Android Studio independently and it works. Thank you!